# getting this error while sending keys Invalid Element State Error

Tags: appium-android

I am trying to send keys to an edit text box but getting this error:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Cannot set the element to '7343897689'. Did you interact with the correct element